# Error in declare multiple dimensional array in TypeScript

Tags: javascript

In my app, I need to define an element like:

```
commandsList:[RegExp, string, string];
```

but when I tried to push the array elements into it, as below:

```
public registerCommand(command:RegExp, cb:string, phrase:string):void{
        this.commandsList.push({ command: command, callback: cb, originalPhrase: phrase });
}
```

I got the below error at the `command:command`

> [ts] Argument of type '{ command: RegExp; callback: string;
>   originalPhrase: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'string | RegExp'.   Object literal may only specify known properties,
>   and 'command' does not exist in type 'string | RegExp'. (parameter)
>   command: RegExp

The full code is in my other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41315930/2441637).

What is the mistake I've, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the best way is to use `interface` like:

```
interface ICommand {
   regexp: RegExp;
   callback: Function;
}
```

then defining the array as:

```
let commandsList: ICommand[];
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it looks like you're trying to push an object, where the array expects a `RegExp | string` type.

Comment: It is a `RegExp` type